# PHP8/EventListener - Getting Socket instance from file descriptor

Tags: sockets, event-listener, file-descriptor, libevent, php-8

PHP8 has introduced Socket class that replaces old socket resource. Now all socket functions works with the instance of this class.

The 2nd argument of EventListener's constructor (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.eventlistener.php) is callback function. It is called when new connection event arises. There is signature of this callback function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/eventlistener.setcallback.php . It receives file descriptor as the 2nd argument.
File descriptor is numeric value, but I need instance of Socket class, because next I will pass it to constructor of EventBufferEvent.

Please advice how can I acquire instance of Socket for this file descriptor?

---

Solution that doesn't work:

I tried to find address and port that are bound to the file descriptor, then create new socket and bind it to this address and port. But that creates new socket with new file descriptor, not related to connection received in callback of event listener.

I'm stuck on finding any useful documentation or code samples for my problem while migrating my event-based socket server to php8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: **you can pass the numeric file descriptor as the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument to `EventBufferEvent::__construct`**.

---

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/eventlistener.setcallback.php . It receives file descriptor as the 2nd argument. File descriptor is numeric value, but I need instance of Socket class, because next I will pass it to constructor of EventBufferEvent.

There is an inaccuracy in the the documentation of [`EventBufferEvent::__construct`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/eventbufferevent.construct.php):

> socket
>
> May be created as a stream(not necessarily by means of sockets extension)

It is slightly misleading because the second argument is actually as flexible as most of the Event functions that accept an "fd" or a "stream". Event tries to get numeric file descriptor from the argument, and if it is already a numeric value, it uses it.

See how the ["Echo server" example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/event.examples.php#example-4235) creates an instance of `EventBufferEvent` for every connection:

```
class MyListenerConnection {
    public function __construct($base, $fd) {
        $this->base = $base;
        $this->bev = new EventBufferEvent($base, $fd, EventBufferEvent::OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE);

// ...

$this->conn[] = new MyListenerConnection($base, $fd);
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know much about Socket class, PHP documentation says it "A fully opaque class". Thus I have to look into C sources of `sockets.so` implementation [sockets.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/sockets/sockets.c). I see, `Socket` object is described by `php_socket` structure.
I look into header file  [php_sockets.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/sockets/php_sockets.h) as well. It contains the function signature `PHP_SOCKETS_API int socket_import_file_descriptor(PHP_SOCKET socket, php_socket *retsock);`. It receives file descriptor of socket connection and results with pointer to structure that defines instance of PHP Socket class. Let's check how [socket_import_file_descriptor()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/sockets/sockets.c#L2162) function is implemented in sockets.c. It does what we need, but it isn't exported to PHP scope, thus we aren't able to call it.

I search for usages of `socket_import_file_descriptor()` among exported functions. It is called from `socket_import_stream()` only. Let's look to PHP documentation of [socket_import_stream(resource $stream): Socket|false](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-import-stream.php). It receives resource and results with instance of Socket. This is what we need, but file descriptor is not a resource. However, there is way to open file descriptor and acquire its resource. Here is solution:

```php
$filename = sprintf("php://fd/%d", $clientResourceFd);
$clientResource = fopen($filename, 'rb');
$clientSocket = socket_import_stream($clientResource);
```

Good news it works in linux. Any advice, how to make it work in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Use can also use an undocumented [`EventUtil::createSocket`](https://bitbucket.org/osmanov/pecl-event/src/87d8edb7c15accf4ecd0a88c0ddec3c1165115d5/php8/classes/event_util.c#event_util.c-252:252) function:

```php
$socket = EventUtil::createSocket($fd);
socket_set_nonblock($socket);
$socketFd = EventUtil::getSocketFd($socket);
```

Only make sure to save the reference to the socket somewhere, if you are using the `$fd` with other classes such as `EventBufferEvent`. Otherwise, the `$socket` variable may be closed together with the underlying file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

php8 can work with this (from pecl-event)

```
PHP_EVENT_METHOD(EventUtil, getSocketFd) {
        zval *pzfd = NULL;
        php_socket *php_sock;

        if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "z", &pzfd) == FAILURE) {
                return;
        }
        php_sock = Z_SOCKET_P(pzfd);
        ENSURE_SOCKET_VALID(php_sock);

        if (Z_ISUNDEF(php_sock->zstream) && (!IS_INVALID_SOCKET(php_sock))) {
            RETURN_LONG(php_sock->bsd_socket);
        }

        RETVAL_LONG(pzfd ? php_event_zval_to_fd(pzfd) : -1);
}
```